# Paypal API Live Credentials not working

Tags: paypal, sdk

I set developed my own site that sells items with a shopping cart. When items are selected, a call is made to paypal's api to create a payment request, then to complete the payment. Seems to work fine with sandbox mode, but with live setting I get the following response :

{ [Error: Response Status : 400]
  response: 
   { name: 'VALIDATION_ERROR',
     details: [ [Object] ],
     message: 'Invalid request - see details',
     information_link: 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR',
     debug_id: 'f8dbb7c22fdf2',
     httpStatusCode: 400 },
  httpStatusCode: 400 }

I was wondering if someone out who has worked with paypal's api to give me some advice.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you paste some code?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue was?